# How do I 'pass down' feature flags to subdependencies in Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm writing a library in Cargo. If this library depends on another library like [`libc`](http://crates.io/crates/libc), which exposes a feature (in this case, `use_std`), how do I make a feature I expose enable or disable that feature in my dependency?

Looking at the [cargo documentation](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-features-section), it looks like there's no official way specified to do this.

Comment: This question has a better answer: [How to pass compiler flags to a sub crate in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50986237/4934640)

Answer (score 28):

From [the documentation you linked to](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-features-section):

> ```
> # Features can be used to reexport features of other packages. The `session`
> # feature of package `awesome` will ensure that the `session` feature of the
> # package `cookie` is also enabled.
> session = ["cookie/session"]
> ```

Is that sufficient?

Comment: Hmm, what if I have a dependency like [`ascii`](https://github.com/tomprogrammer/rust-ascii), which exposes a `no_std` flag - which I want to _disable_ if my `use_std` flag is enabled?

Comment: @burtonageo an interesting question, you could probably ask a separate top-level question for that! It might even be a feature request. Specifically for `no_std` though, I feel like I heard that the right thing to do is to have a *default feature* that enables using things from `std`, so perhaps the ascii crate is just backwards...

Comment: Yeah, I've heard that features are meant to be additive, not subtractive, so I think my best bet would be to make a pull request to them.