# How to pass compiler flags to a sub crate in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have the crates `A` and `B`. `A` depends on `B` and `B` has a feature named `some_feature`.

I can build `B` using cargo by running `cargo build --features=some_feature`, but how can I set the same features for `A` that I can choose to enable or disable `some_feature` for underlying crate `B` when compiling `A`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply forward the feature specified in `A`:

```
# A/Cargo.toml

[features]
some-feature = ["B/some-feature"]

[dependencies]
B = "*"
```

This will compile `B` with `--features=some_feature` if you pass `--features=some_feature` to `A`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to configure the manifest, it's as simple as the [doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-features-section) say:

```toml
[dependencies.awesome]
version = "1.3.5"
default-features = false # do not include the default features, and optionally
                         # cherry-pick individual features
features = ["secure-password", "civet"]
```