# How can I activate features in all my crates?

Tags: compilation, rust, rust-cargo

I want to conditionally enable run-time checks and logging, independently from each other and from debug and release mode. So I've started adding two [features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/conditional-compilation.html) to my project, one called "invariant-checking" and one called "logging". Ultimately i want their use to be through macros I define in a crate which is visible project-wide.

I had assumed that if I filled out the [features section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-features-section) the same way in all of the crates the same way then when I activated the feature while compiling the bin crate, then all the lib crates would also have the feature enabled, but this is not the case! How can I enable and disable features across multiple crates? Hopefully this can be done by only changing one thing like the command-line arguments to cargo.

To clarify exactly what I want, [here's an example](https://github.com/Ryan1729/features_across_multiple_crates/tree/a5a57411388d4593d52e1c4fa8d818b9e9b209b7), which I will also reproduce below:

There are three crates, the main, bin, crate, and two lib crates, called "middle" and "common". Here are the relevant parts of the relevant files:

*main.rs*

```
extern crate common;
extern crate middle;

fn main() {
    common::check!();

    middle::run();

    println!("done");
}
```

the main *Cargo.toml*

```
[dependencies]

[dependencies.common]
path = "libs/common"

[dependencies.middle]
path = "libs/middle"

[features]
default = []
invariant-checking = []
logging = []
```

middle's *lib.rs*

```
extern crate common;

pub fn run() {
    common::check!();

    common::run();
}
```

middle's *Cargo.toml*

```
[dependencies]

[dependencies.common]
path = "../common"

[features]
default = []
invariant-checking = []
logging = []
```

common's *lib.rs*

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! check {
    () => {{
        if cfg!(feature = "invariant-checking") {
            println!("invariant-checking {}:{}", file!(), line!());
        }
        if cfg!(feature = "logging") {
            println!("logging {}:{}", file!(), line!());
        }
    }};
}

pub fn run() {
    check!()
}
```

and finally common's *Cargo.toml*

```
[dependencies]

[features]
default = []
invariant-checking = []
logging = []
```

When i run `cargo run --features "invariant-checking,logging"` I get the following output

```
invariant-checking src\main.rs:5
logging src\main.rs:5
done
```

but want it to log in middle and common as well. How can I transform this project such that it will do that, and still allow me to get only "done" as output by changing only one place?

Comment: You should define different macros depending on what features are selected in `common`, so feature selection happens at compile time and only in the `common` crate.  Then you only need to declare the features in that crate, and switching the features will have global effect, as long as all crates use the same version of`common`.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How do I 'pass down' feature flags to subdependencies in Cargo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40021555/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @SvenMarnach That certainly sounds like less setup and maintenance than passing the flags to every single crate. If I understand correctly you are suggesting defining multiple macro with the same name and selecting which are enabled with attributes like `#[cfg(feature = "logging")]` and `#[cfg(not(feature = "logging"))]`. That works. And at least in my toy example I only need to mention the features in the main  and `common`'s `Cargo.toml` files!

Comment: @Shepmaster I suppose that previous answer might have technically allowed me to figure out the answer, but I found gnzlbg 's explanation more helpful than just pointing to small paragraph of documentation I missed. Go ahead and mark this question as you please though.

Comment: @Ryan1729 Yes, that's what I meant.  I can expand in an answer now that I'm at my desk (wrote the comment on mobile).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I enable and disable features across multiple crates?

A `Cargo.toml` can add features that transitively enable other features which are allowed to belong to dependencies.

For example, in the `Cargo.toml` of a crate which depends on crates `foo` and `bar`:

```
[dependencies]
foo = "0.1"
bar = "0.1"

[features]
default = []
invariant-checking = [ "foo/invariant-checking", "bar/invariant-checking" ]
logging = [ "foo/logging", "bar/logging" ]
```

This crate adds the `invariant-checking` and `logging` features. Enabling them transitively enables the respective features of the crates `foo` and `bar`, so that

```
cargo build --features=logging,invariant-checking
```

will enable the `logging` and `invariant-checking` features in this crate and also in its dependencies `foo` and `bar` as well.

In your particular case, you probably want `main` to transitively enable the features of `middle` and `common`, and for `middle` to transitively enable the features of `common`.

Answer (score 1):

The macro definitions in their current form have a problem:  The code inside the macro gets inlined whenever the macro is used, and then compiled in the context where it got inlined.  Since you use runtime feature checks like

```
if cfg!(feature = "invariant-checking")
```

this means that you need to define the features in every crate where you are using the macro.  In the `common` crate itself, on the other hand, the feature is never queried and thus redundant.

This seems completely backwards to me.  The feature flag should be *only* queried in the common crate, and using the macro should not require first defining a feature flag in the crate that uses it.  For this reason, I suggest using compile-time checks to select what macro to define:

```
#[cfg(feature = "invariant-checking")]
macro_rules! check_invariant {
    () => ( println!("invariant-checking {}:{}", file!(), line!()); )
}

#[cfg(not(feature = "invariant-checking"))]
macro_rules! check_invariant {
    () => ()
}

#[cfg(feature = "logging")]
macro_rules! logging {
    () => ( println!("logging {}:{}", file!(), line!()); )
}

#[cfg(not(feature = "logging"))]
macro_rules! logging {
    () => ()
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! check {
    () => ( check_invariant!(); logging!(); )
}
```

This way, you will only need to define the feature in the `common` crate, as it should be.  As long as you only use a single version of that crate, switching the flag on and off has global effect.

Comment: I had assumed that `if cfg!(...) { /*...*/ }` would be easy to remove by the compiler. I tried out some simple examples on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Q2Nnex) and it seems like those are successfully removed. It's possible that more complex cases with lots of `cfg!` calls aren't though, so this technique seems useful since it should work in every case.

Comment: @Ryan1729 if the configuration setting is known statically at compile time, the optimizer should _always_ be able to resolve the branch statically.  However, the fact that this is a runtime check was only a side note.  The more important point is the context in which the feature gets resolved.  This version resolves all feature queries in the `common` crate, while your version resolved them in the crate that uses the macro.